Prove ${\rm tr}(\rho^2)={\rm tr}((\rho \otimes \rho')S)$ with $S$ the swap operator
I'm trying to prove $P(\rho)={\rm tr}((\rho \otimes \rho')S)$, where $P(\rho)={\rm tr}(\rho^2)$ is the purity and $S$ is the swap operator. My question is that since ${\rm tr}(AB)={\rm tr}(BA)$, do we have $${\rm tr}((\rho \otimes \rho')S)={\rm tr}(S(\rho \otimes \rho'))={\rm tr}(\rho' \otimes \rho)={\rm tr}(\rho'){\rm tr}(\rho)\,?$$
However, I just cannot get a result that matches ${\rm tr}(\rho^2)$ by expanding $\rho$ in ${\rm tr}((\rho \otimes \rho')S)$ or ${\rm tr}(\rho'){\rm tr}(\rho)$.

First, your $\rho'$ should be $\rho$, then the formula is correct (else what is $\rho'$ even supposed to be?)

(2/2) Aside from that, your approach does not work because the swap operator $S$ swaps vectors, not matrices. So it is not true that $S(X\otimes Y)=Y\otimes X$ once $X,Y$ are operators. Instead, try expanding $\rho=\sum_{j,k}\langle j|X|k\rangle |j\rangle\langle k|$ in the expression ${\rm tr}((\rho\otimes\rho)S)$ to arrive at ${\rm tr}(\rho^2)$. Can you take it from here?

@FrederikvomEnde  Could you please say more about expanding $\rho=\sum_{jk}<j|X|k>|j><k|$? $\rho$ is a density operator of the ensemble ${p(x),|\phi_x>}$ then $\rho=\sum_x p(x)|\phi_x><\phi_x|$, how can we expand $\rho$ in your form?

That's just the usual basis expansion, and works not just for density operators but for all matrices. The key is that, given any orthonormal basis (say, the computational basis $|j\rangle$), the identity matrix can be written as ${\bf1}=\sum_j|j\rangle\langle j|$. Thus \begin{align*}\rho={\bf1}\cdot\rho\cdot{\bf1}&=\Big(\sum_j|j\rangle\langle j|\Big)\rho\Big(\sum_k|k\rangle\langle k|\Big)\&=\sum_{j,k}|j\rangle\langle j|\rho|k\rangle\langle k|\&=\sum_{j,k}\langle j|\rho|k\rangle|j\rangle\langle k|
\end{align*}

(2/2) But if you only care about proving this for quantum states, you can also use the decomposition $\rho=\sum_x p(x)|\phi_x\rangle\langle\phi_x|$ you mentioned; inserting it into ${\rm tr}((\rho\otimes\rho)S)$ will also do the job!

@FrederikvomEnde is this correct? thank you!
\begin{align}
&tr{(\rho \otimes \rho)S}\
&=tr{\sum_{xy}p(x)p(y) (|\phi_x\rangle \otimes|\phi_y\rangle) (\langle\phi_x|\otimes \langle\phi_y|)S}\
&=tr{\sum_{xy}p(x)p(y) (\langle\phi_x|\otimes \langle\phi_y|)S(|\phi_x\rangle \otimes |\phi_y\rangle) }\
&=tr{\sum_{xy}p(x)p(y) (\langle\phi_x|\otimes \langle\phi_y|)(|\phi_y\rangle \otimes |\phi_x\rangle) }\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&=tr{\sum_{xy}p(x)p(y) \langle\phi_x|\phi_y\rangle \langle\phi_y|\phi_x\rangle }\
&=\sum_{xy}p(x)p(y)\sum_i \langle\phi_x|\phi_y\rangle \langle\phi_y|i\rangle\langle i|\phi_x\rangle=tr{\rho^2}
\end{align}

The equation in the title (after correcting as suggested by @FrederikvomEnde) can easily be proven using tensor networks, see diagram and equation $(3a)$ in this answer.

@hzxscyq That's the idea, yes. You can skip the last step by using that $\langle\phi_x|\phi_y\rangle=\delta_{xy}$ (i.e. the states from the ensemble are orthonormal) so the sum simplifies to $\sum_xp(x)^2={\rm tr}(\rho^2)$. Either way, feel free to post your calcluation as an answer to your own question!

@FrederikvomEnde, why does the swap operator not apply to matrices? I thought that the state of two registers simply gets exchanged under a swap?

@JRT $S(\rho\otimes\sigma)\neq\sigma\otimes\rho$, $(\rho\otimes\sigma)S\neq (\sigma\otimes\rho)$ (in general), $S(\rho\otimes\sigma)S=\sigma\otimes\rho$, $S(|\psi\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle)=|\phi\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle$

In fact, we have a more general equality:
$$
{\text Tr}(AB) = {\text Tr}((A\otimes B) S),
$$
for any square matrices $A,B$.
If $A = |a\rangle\langle b|$ and $B = |c\rangle\langle d|$ then
$$
{\text Tr}(AB) = \langle b|c \rangle\langle d|a \rangle
$$
and
$$
{\text Tr}((A\otimes B) S) = 
{\text Tr}(|a\rangle\langle d| \otimes |c\rangle\langle b|) = 
\langle d|a \rangle\langle b|c \rangle, 
$$
so they match. But both sides are linear in $A$ and $B$ hence the equality is true for any $A,B$.

You can easily prove that identity using graphical notation that depicts tensor contractions by lines:


EDIT: It seems like the graphical notation is less known than I anticipated. Doesn't matter. The above equation also has an index form
$${\rm Tr}\left( (A \otimes B) S \right) = A^a_b B^c_d S_{ac}^{bd} = A^a_b B^c_d \delta_a^d \delta^b_c = A^a_b B^b_a = {\rm Tr}\left( AB \right), $$
where I used the $S^{bd}_{ac} = \delta_a^d \delta_c^b$ to write the elements of the SWAP operator and Einstein's summation convention indicating summation over double indices.

What do these diagrams mean?

Every line is an index and joined lines are contractions over indices. It is actually very common, see Penrose calculus.

+1 Nice application of tensor diagrams. This notation genuinely makes the proof simpler and more intuitive (another such case is quantum teleportation). Incidentally, quantum circuits can be interpreted as a subset of tensor diagrams (where e.g. return lines are not allowed).
